# How to detect a specific character before changing formatting in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe is like this in the following...

```
    0    1    2
0   1   02    3
1   1   04   04
2   1   54   04
3   1    *    *
```

However, my desired outcome is this...

```
    0    1   2
0   1    2   3
1   1    4   4
2   1   54   4
3   1    *   *
```

I want to format the 02 to only 2. One of my solution is to use and if-else method to avoid "*" while 02 will be formatted to 2. but it didn't work, i presume that MasterDf.iloc[:,2] refers to the whole column.

```
if MasterDf.iloc[:,2].str.contains('*'):
    pass
else:
    MasterDf.iloc[:,2] = MasterDf.iloc[:,2].astype('int64')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with a regex:

```
out = df.replace(r'^0', '', regex=True)
```

*NB. if you only want to remove `0`s when followed by digits, use `df.replace('^0(?=\d+)', '', regex=True)`.*

Output:

```
   0   1  2
0  1   2  3
1  1   4  4
2  1  54  4
3  1   *  *
```

Regex:

```
^    # match start of string
0    # match 0
```

More convoluted alternative, using [`str.lstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html) and in place modification:

```
df.update(df.select_dtypes('object').apply(lambda c: c.str.lstrip('0')))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, how about `applymap` with a custom converter

```
def convert(value):
    try: 
        return int(value)
    except ValueError:
        return value

df2 = df.applymap(convert)
print (df2)

   0   1  2
0  1   2  3
1  1   4  4
2  1  54  4
3  1   *  *
```

if you need to apply it to specific columns:

```
df[[1, 2]] = df[[1, 2]].applymap(convert)
```

Comment: what if the 0 column has alphabets? "*" will be return to replace them, would return str(value) work?

Comment: @Kenny yes it would! updated